# can't install gem dm-adapter-simpledb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

any idea what should I do? this is error message from bundler

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "dm-core":
  In Gemfile:
    dm-adapter-simpledb (>= 0) ruby depends on
      dm-core (~> 0.10.0) ruby

    dm-core (1.2.0)
```

here is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'json'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-graph'
gem 'prawn-layout'
gem 'prawn-fast-png'
gem 'prawn-qrcode'
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'dm-core'
gem 'dm-mysql-adapter'
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
gem 'dm-migrations'
gem 'dm-adapter-simpledb'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'dm-paperclip'
gem 'savon'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'SystemTimer', :require => "system_timer", :platforms => :ruby_18
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'mail'
```

Comment: please fid Gemfile in updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `dm-core` gem from the Gemfile. You don't need it anyway - `dm-adapter-simpledb` requires it.

If you absolutely must include `dm-core` gem in the Gemfile, set it to the version required by `dm-adapter-simpledb` in Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 0):

dm-adapter-simpledb in your gemfile depends on dm-core version 0.10.0, the one you have is 1.2.0.  either remove it as Lukas suggested or update your gemfile: `dm-core', '~> 0.10.0'

Comment: thanks, I cant because data_mapper depends on dm-core 1.2.0. Looks loke there is no way to use newest data_mapper and dm-adapter-simpledb at the same time

Comment: can you post the output of bundle show dm-adapter-simpledb and bundle show dm-core?